# H5BP Build Script Issue

Tags: html5boilerplate, build-script

Every time I try to use HTML5 Build Script I get this errors:

```
-js.main.concat:
     [echo] Concatenating Main JS scripts based on index.html...
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/java.lang.NullPointerException does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/at does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/ScriptsToConcat.handleStartTag(ScriptsToConcat.java:38) does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/at does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/javax.swing.text.html.parser.DocumentParser.handleStartTag(DocumentParser.java:143) does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/at does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser.startTag(Parser.java:421) does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/at does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser.parseTag(Parser.java:1943) does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/at does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser.parseContent(Parser.java:2061) does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/at does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:2228) does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/at does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/javax.swing.text.html.parser.DocumentParser.parse(DocumentParser.java:105) does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/at does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator.parse(ParserDelegator.java:84) does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/at does not exist.
   [concat] /Volumes/[...]/intermediate/ScriptsToConcat.main(ScriptsToConcat.java:50) does not exist.
```

("[...]" is for not showing my client's name, the route is OK)

I'm using latest h5bp build script and running "ant build"

I have the following in the html:

```
  <!-- scripts concatenated and minified via build script -->
  <script  src="js/plugins.js"></script>
  <!-- end scripts-->
```

and in the "js" folder I have a 12k plugins.js and a blank scripts.js (just in case I left it)

I'm using Mac OS 10.6.8 with latest Java.
The default.properties has all the default values.
I tried changing

```
tool.yuicompressor          = yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
```

to

```
tool.yuicompressor          = closure-compiler-v1346.jar
```

but the same keeps happening. A new safasg.js file is in /publish/js/ but it's blank (actually 2 lines os whitespace)

I don't know how to troubleshoot this

Comment: Have you found a fix for this?

Comment: not yet. i ended up not building it and minify by hand :(

Comment: I did the same. I had to do it all manually.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
<!-- end scripts-->
```

There should be a space between the 's' and the '-->' part:

```
<!-- end scripts -->
```

Comment: changing it gives me this error:
BUILD FAILED
/Volumes/.../build/build.xml:127: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Volumes/.../build/build.xml:476: Could not find file /Volumes/.../intermediate/js/scripts-concat.min.js to generate checksum for.